# Properly passing NSManagedObjects between views when using ARC? Memory warning & crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Hi I have a nasty memory management issue under ARC and cannot figure out how to solve it. The problem stands like this, I have these objects:

**ObjectManager** - a singleton that does fetchRequests to core data and fetches one or more NSManagedObjects

**UIViewControllerA** - a view controller in which I have a button "PassManagedObject" and a property declared as below:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ManagedObject *objectForToday;
```

in **viewDidLoad** on **UIViewControllerA**, I call the method **refreshDailyObject** which does this:

```
self.objectForToday = nil;
self.objectForToday  = [[ObjectManager sharedManager] getDailyObject];
```

if I **tap** the **PassManagedObject** button I **create UIViewControllerB**, **pass** the **objectForToday** to it and **display** it, see below

```
- (IBAction)passManagedObjectTapped:(id)sender {
       UIViewControllerB *viewController = [[UIViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIViewControllerB"];
       viewController.object = self.objectForToday;
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
 }
```

**UIViewControllerB** has a property declared like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ManagedObject *object;
```

and a button "**Back**" which does this:

```
- (IBAction)backAction:(id)sender {
    self.object = nil;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Now the problem is this. If I tap continuously passManagedObjectTapped and then backAction, and again passManagedObjectTapped and again backAction and then again passManagedObjectTapped and automate this I'm getting eventually **Received Memory Warning 1**, and then **crash**.

The Instruments doesn't show any leaks but my memory allocation keeps slowly going up.

I am using **ARC** under iOS4.3 & iOS5. I've been struggling to figuring out what is wrong for a day now. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to add this. If I comment the line viewController.object = self.objectFoToday in passManagedObjectTapped: so I'm not passing anything to UIViewControllerB the code works without a problem, no crash or memory warnings.

Comment: why do you pass the MO to the new ViewController. you got your singleton, so just let the new ViewController get the MO itself. if you need it in both controllers than get it in the first and pass it to the second but do an `@property(weak) ManagedObject *object;`

Comment: @pkyeck littering the use of singletons across multiple classes is a code smell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The self.object = nil; and self.objectForToday = nil; isn't necessary - ARC and the synthesized properties setters already take care of that.

It seems pretty likely that you have a circular reference somewhere. Do you have any situations where object A has a strong reference to object B and object B has a strong reference to object A?

If so, just change one of those references to weak instead (or assign if you want to support iOS 4.3).

Comment: You were right. I finally figured it out. So the bug was not in the code posted above (the code posted above was fetching an object from the core data and then populating a table view in UIViewControllerB). The bug was this: In my UITableViewCell subclass I was having a strong reference to the parentView, and the parentView of course was having a strong reference with the UITableViewCell so this was the circular reference. As soon as I've set the property in UITableViewCell to assign the nightmare was gone. It took me one night to figure this out so it is most likely I won't repeat this error.

Comment: Another thing that I've discovered that is extremely important when developing with ARC is to make sure Zombie Objects are not enabled. If they are enabled you'll experience the same behaviour described in the question.